# Issues using mmc_power_up while compiling kernel module for using SDIO port

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a kernel module for using the SD card port for communicating with another peripheral (a digital signal processor TigerSHARC) to a Colibri PXA320 board. The kernel source uses the functions `mmc_power_up` and `mmc_power_off` for controlling the port and runs using the mmc driver provided in the kernel. 
The source code right now has the following includes

```
#include <linux/module.h>   
#include <linux/kernel.h>   
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/scatterlist.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>

#include <linux/mmc/host.h>
#include <linux/mmc/card.h>
#include <linux/mmc/mmc.h>
#include <linux/mmc/sd.h>
#include <linux/mmc/sdio.h>
#include <linux/mmc/sdio_func.h>
#include <linux/mmc/sdio_ids.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
```

The path variables added are

```
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/tools/usr/local/arm/oe/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/tools/usr/local/arm/oe/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/include:$PATH
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex:$PATH
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex/include/asm-arm:$PATH
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex/drivers/mmc/core:$PATH
export PATH=$KSRCPATH/src/u-boot-2010.09-toradex/tools:$PATH
```

where `$KSRCPATH` is the kernel source folder.

When I compile the kernel modules I am getting the following message :

```
WARNING: "mmc_set_bus_width" [/mnt/hgfs/Colibri_Linux/Linux/SDIO_Driver/unet_sdio.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mmc_power_up" [/mnt/hgfs/Colibri_Linux/Linux/SDIO_Driver/unet_sdio.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "mmc_power_off" [/mnt/hgfs/Colibri_Linux/Linux/SDIO_Driver/unet_sdio.ko] undefined!
```

I checked the kernel source tree and the function s are defined in the `core.c` file in `$KSRCPATH/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex/drivers/mmc/core` but they dont have any declarations defined in `core.h` for them.

My makefile right now is :

```
KDIR = $(KSRCPATH)/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex

obj-m += unet_sdio.o

all:  
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
    make install

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean

install:
    cp unet_sdio.ko /mnt/hgfs/Colibri_Linux/
```

I have declared the functions are extern in my source code

```
/*! External (MMC) Functions */
extern void mmc_power_up(struct mmc_host *host);
extern void mmc_power_off(struct mmc_host *host);
```

I am guessing my kernel module in not getting linked into `core.c` in `$KSRCPATH/src/linux-2.6.35.9-toradex/drivers/mmc/core` and hence the functions are marked as undefined.

What changes do I need to make in the source code or the makefile to link the my source code and core.c together.

EDIT: I am able to boot the colibri PXA320 device with the compiled kernel and  kallsyms does show that the mmc_power_off and mmc_power_on functions are available in the kernel on the colibri PXA320 device:

```
root@toradex:/home/modem# grep mmc_power* /proc/kallsyms
c0226a50 t mmc_power_off
c0226ce0 t mmc_power_up
c02277ec T mmc_power_save_host
c022796c T mmc_power_restore_host
c0229490 t mmc_power_restore
```

Comment: Are you able to use recent stable kernel?

Comment: yes, i can boot up the colibri PXA320 board with the compiled kernel, its only while my compile my kernel module file that I am getting this issue. The problem is basically since mmc_power_off and mmc_power_on not have any declarations in a header file and are not exported, I dont know how to call them in my module

Comment: Also kallsyms does how that the mmc_power_off and mmc_power_on functions are available in the kernel :


root@toradex:/home/modem# grep mmc_power* /proc/kallsyms
c0226a50 t mmc_power_off
c0226ce0 t mmc_power_up
c02277ec T mmc_power_save_host
c022796c T mmc_power_restore_host
c0229490 t mmc_power_restore

Comment: Isn't declaration of mmc_power_off, mmc_power_up and mmc_set_bus_width are defined under $(KSRCPATH)/drivers/mmc/core/core.h ? may be you need to add the proper include path

Comment: Those function are not supposed for usage outside of mmc subsystem. You have to use the API provided by SDIO module.

Comment: @sagar : mmc_set_bus_width is but the power on and off functions are not defined in the header file. As Andy said, thses functions technically are not supposed to be used outside the mmc sub-system.